# ¿Como se mapearía esta relacion con keys compuestas?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

```
  @Entity    
    @IdClass(PUsuarioId.class)
    public class PUsuario {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DNI")
    @NotNull
    private String dni;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TELEFONO")
    @NotNull
    private Integer tel;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODIGO")
    @NotNull
    private Integer codigo;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CALLE")
    @NotNull
    private String calle;

}
```

> Y esta otra clase mapeada:

```
 @Entity    
    @IdClass(UsuarioId.class)
    public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DNI")
    @NotNull
    private String dni;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TELEFONO")
    @NotNull
    private Integer tel;
}
```

Las columnas de **PUsuario** forman la PK de la entidad, además dni y teléfono son la FK que hacen referencia a Usuario. Un PUsuario solo tiene una relación OneToOne con Usuario. ¿Como se mapearía esta relación?

Answer (score 0):

En ambos casos, necesitas crear una clase independiente para definir la clave compuesta:

```
public class PUsuarioPK {
    private Long employeId;
    private String telType;
}
```

Una vez hecho lo defines de la siguiente manera:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PUsuario")
@IdClass(value = PUsuarioPK.class)
public class PUsuario{
    @Id
    private String dni;
    @Id
    private Integer telefono;
    @Id
    private Integer codigo;
    @Id
    private Integer calle;
}
```

Espero que te sirva.